# Experience Manager configuration issue. StorageTransactionId is getting appeneded to page url

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, dd4t java and I have configured experience manager on my test environment. 
When I click on finish editing in experience manager, I am getting below error message.

Original Url:
dd4t/root/index.html

Changed URL:
dd4t/root/index_7c51e8a3-fdcd-465a-8ead-72770845566d.html' and publication '1003'.

**Itemnotfound exception**.

This is happeneing after editing page in XPM and clicked on finish editing.

There is no error logs in preview webservice configuration and my test application.
I am not able to find out the place where this text is getting added to requested url.

Did somebody experienced this problem before.

Comment: Exception message for e.g.:
org.dd4t.contentmodel.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException: Unable to find page by url '/dd4t/root/index_002ed1cb-bbb6-4854-9def-765d083193c3.html' and publication '1003'.

One can see that the session id is getting appended to the url while requesting it from broker api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a root cause for above mentioned problem: 
- When we configured application for XPM, SDL Tridion wants us to add "PageContentFilter" and "ImageFilter" into web.xml file.
This changes the url of actual page we are editing in tridion.
SDL Tridion does this to keep unique files for editing session and it tries to find the same file on local storage.

But DD4T Doesn't work as per this configuration, pagecontroller which is a core part of DD4T still searches for the page with original url.
to avoid above mentioned problem just comment out "PageContentFilter" and "ImageFilter" from web.xml and it should work perfectly.

Regards,
Shailesh